# Circuity Breaker 2 pole Amp Label

Tags: circuit-breaker

Old breaker needs replacing. Is this a 2 pole 40 amp breaker (40 each pole) or a 2 pole 20 amp breaker? (20 + 20 = 40).

[image]

Comment: What does the breaker control?

Comment: look at the terminal lugs on the bottom of the breaker. If you see one lug screw it's a single breaker. Even though it's not in the photo I will guess there are 2 screw lugs so this particular breaker can be used for (2) 40 Amp circuits at 120 Volts or (1) 40 Amp at 240 Volts.

Answer (score 1):

It's a 40 ampere double pole breaker.

It can supply two 40 ampere 120 volt circuits, one 40 ampere 240 volt circuit, or any combination of the two.

It may seem complicated, but it's really quite simple. Go to the hardware or home improvement store, and ask for a double pole 40 ampere breaker.

Comment: so both are 40? not 20 each? or something?

Comment: @PeachPassion It's like two 40 amp breakers stuck together.  The amperage doesn't get added up.  Each "side" can be a 40A 120v circuit (less common), or you can use both sides together for a 40A 240v circuit.

Comment: @PeachPassion On other brand breakers, each side would be separately labeled "40" with a blank tie between. (for example, http://www.homedepot.com/p/Square-D-Homeline-40-Amp-Two-Pole-Circuit-Breaker-HOM240CP/202353324). It's the same either way.